# Ruby DevKit Unable to Download Date from Rubygens.org

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-development-kit

I've installed the ruby devkit on Windows 7 but it's unable to install json using the following command:

```
gem install json --platform=ruby
```

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A:
>   unknown protocol (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

I'm on ruby 2.3.1p112 with RubyGems 2.5.1.

Comment: Simply use this link https://rubygems.org/gems/json and download it manually :) Click and download options available there. OR direct link - https://rubygems.org/downloads/json-2.0.2-java.gem for `version 2.0.2`. You could use the first link to select the version.

Comment: Thanks @MathewsMathai, but I was actually just using json for a test. Infact I'm aiming to get Jekyell up and running.

Comment: Well not used to ruby and gems. So I am not of much help I guess. Welcome Though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Gemfile, change the first line in Gemfile from https to http, it should do the trick.
Also, you can install gems global by creating a Gemfile and running bundle install from the directory the Gemfile is created. So, instead of using the gem install command, create a Gemfile and run bundle install in it.
This is the original

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'test'
```

Change to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'test'
```

If you don't, you can pass the -s option to gem install and specify the url to http://rubygems.org

Comment: Thanks barosus :) I just tried the -s option but I'm getting "Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - too many connection resets (http://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)". And unfortunately I hit a catch 22 with bundler because I can't gem install bundler... ahhh! Any ideas?